# php prepared sql function

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am wondering if there is a PHP OOP based class or any other database abstraction classes that are build into a fairly basic one or few file PHP Class framework. Something that can allow to call query's with function like syntax instead of going truth standard PDO or mysql_* type of syntax like

```
class Session {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    } 

    public function write() {
        $this->db->query(...);
    }
}


$db = new DB(...);
$session = new Session($db);
```

Comment: MySQLi should be able to do this. Have you taken a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php?

Comment: What functionality are you looking for that [PDO](http://us.php.net/PDO) doesn't already have?

Comment: @DCoder sorry updated the question to make more sense of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an adapter, it handles all the database related stuff for you. There's plenty out there on [Github](https://github.com/search?q=mysql%20adapter&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Repositories&l=PHP), a search on "mysql adapter" reveals a variety of libraries.

Comment: I updated the question, so its like a class that provides function which intern trigger SQL query's correct? like public function delete() would perform a delete task. So based on my comment and updated question I should look for "mysql adapter" correct?

Comment: @Cl' Yes, it should exactly what you're looking for. It's basically a library you can include in your application to handle all the database stuff for you, rather than re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: thanks as I was wondering what such are called, I recall seeing some build into a basic PHP framework but I can't recall what it was all I know it was on GitHub. And is there any in particular you would recommend?

Comment: Well thank you @Oldskool looking at GitHub I think I will go with Aura.Sql seems like fairly simple and light. And ones more thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_GET['username']));
```

MySQLi:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = s');
$query->bind_param('s', $_GET['username']);
```

These extensions have built-in functions like creating prepared queries.

Comment: Thank you for you're time but, this is quite not it. I was referring to simplified request on a page like $result = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM foo'); instead of having to write the PDO. The PDO is handled by a SQL adapter with statements already prepared like delete, update and so forth. But still thanks :)